# Evaluating contour integral of complex conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

This is part of a homework assignment. Any hints will be useful, I haven't made any progress. I need to evaluate:
$$
\int_{\left\vert z - 1\right\vert = 1}
\overline{z}^{\,n}\,\mathrm{d}z\,,\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Do you know how to parametrize $|z-1|=1$, for example?

Comment: $z = 1+ e^{it}$, $t\in\cdots$

Comment: Thank you. So $\bar{z}^n = (1 + e^{-it})^n$. How do I progress from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=1+e^{i t}$, where $t \in [0,2 \pi]$.  Then the integral is equal to

$$i \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, e^{i t} \, \left ( 1+e^{-i t} \right )^n $$

If you expand the binomial using the binomial theorem, you will find that only one of the terms results in a non-zero integral.  From there, getting to the final answer is simple.  The result is $i 2 \pi n$.  Note that this result is at odds with the result predicted by Cauchy's theorem, which is zero.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{\verts{z - 1}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
\overline{z}^{\,n}\,\dd z
\,\right\vert_{\,n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

Note that $\ds{1 =\pars{z - 1}\pars{\overline{z} - 1} =
\pars{z - 1}\overline{z} - z + 1 \implies \overline{z} = {z \over z - 1}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{\verts{z - 1}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
\overline{z}^{\,n}\,\dd z
\,\right\vert_{\,n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}} =
\int_{\verts{z - 1}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,{z^{n} \over
\pars{z - 1}^{n}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n}}\,\dd z
\end{align}

---

- $\ds{\large n < 0:}$ The integrand is singular at the "contour point" $\ds{z = -1}$.

---

- $\ds{\large n = 0:}$ The integral vanishes out: There's not any pole inside the contour.

---

- $\ds{\large n > 0:}$
  \begin{align}
  &\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{\verts{z - 1}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
  \overline{z}^{\,n}\,\dd z
  \,\right\vert_{\,n\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}_{\,\geq\ 1}}} =
  \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{n}}
  \,\dd z
  \\[5mm] = &\
  2\pi\ic{n \choose n - 1} = \bbx{2n\pi\ic} \\ &
  \end{align}